# Copy multiple lines Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I duplicate 6 lines in notepad++?

For example I have:

```
a 01
a 02
a 03
```

And I want to make like this:

```
a 01
a 01
a 01
a 01
a 01
a 01
a 02
a 02
a 02
a 02
a 02
a 02
a 03
a 03
a 03
a 03
a 03
a 03
```

I just try with regex 3 times:

```
Find what : ^(.*)$
Replace with : $1\n$1
```

But i got 8 lines, not 6 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that result running that 3 times, because you duplicate all the lines 3 times going from 1->2->4->8 lines.

If you want 6 lines, you can either match with `^.*$` (you don't need the capture group, `$0` refers to the whole match) and write the full repetition of all the lines `$0\n$0\n$0\n$0\n$0\n$0`

Or you can use the pattern `^(.*)` with the replacement just 1 time to duplicate the lines

Then replace per 2 lines as `$0` now refers to 2 of the same consecutive lines due to the capture group and the backreference `\1`

```
^(.*)\R\1
```

Replace with 3 times the whole match:

```
$0\n$0\n$0
```

[image]